# Alternative q-Analog

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

Wikipedia gives the following definition of a q-analog: "In mathematics, a q-analog of a theorem, identity or expression is a generalization involving a new parameter $q$ that returns the original theorem, identity or expression in the limit as $q \rightarrow 1$. Typically, mathematicians are interested in q-analogs that arise naturally, rather than in arbitrarily contriving q-analogs of known results."

There seem to exists, for basic mathematical objects like; the numbers, factorial, binomial coefficient,... a well-known q-analog established as convention, however for other lesser known objects like specific types of numbers, or derivatives, there seem to be a few different types of q-analogs all with their own unique properties. These q-analogs are all still based off of the 'basic building block' of all q-analogs, which is the q-number

$${[n]}_q = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^k$$
Which has the arithemtic properties
$${[n m]}_q = {[n]}_q{[m]}_{q^n}$$
and
$${[n+m]}_q = {[n]}_q+q^n{[m]}_q$$

My question is just if there are other known q-analogs of, for example the number. Perhaps even known q-analogs that return the original theorem when $q \rightarrow x$ for some $x \neq 1$? Of course anyone could arbitrarily create a q-analog like $n^q$ so when $q \rightarrow 1$ returns $n$ but that doesn't seem that useful. Any contribution is appreciated

---

Edit: Just to add this here in case anyone is interested. I found something called a [d-analog](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/d-Analog.html) from [this paper](https://inria.hal.science/inria-00074422/PDF/RR-2249.pdf) here. Regardless of the notation, this is relevant to the post, and since it doesn't seem very popular I thought I could share it here and maybe someone finds it interesting.

### Bounty

A +100 bounty is set for anyone who can create/showcase a well-defined and interesting alternative analog for some basic 'building-block' mathematical object like a number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. You can go into as much detail, perhaps even formulating $n!$, analog derivatives, $n \in \mathbb{Q}$, showcasing how it is useful, etc.
Bounty goes to the best one! Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is about alternative $q$-analogs.

> My question is just if there are other known q-analogs of, for example the number.

As stated in the question itself

> Of course anyone could arbitrarily create a q-analog like $n^q$
> so when $q \rightarrow 1$ returns $n$ but that doesn't seem that
> useful.

One important arithmetic property of the integers
is the divisibility relation. The well-known
$q$-analog $\,[n]_q\,$ has this divisibility property.
It is just one example of a
[divisibility sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence). From Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, a divisibility sequence is an integer sequence $(a_{n})$ indexed by positive integers $n$ such that
> $$ {\text{if }}m\mid n{\text{ then }}a_{m}\mid a_{n} $$
> for all $m, n$. That is, whenever one index is a multiple
> of another one, then the corresponding term also is a
> multiple of the other term. The concept can be generalized
> to sequences with values in any ring where the concept of
> divisibility is defined.

After this is a list of examples of integer divisibility
sequences. The last two examples are

> - More generally, any
>   [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence)
>   of the first kind $U_n(P,Q)$ is a divisibility sequence. Moreover,
>   it is a strong divisibility sequence when $\gcd(P,Q) = 1$.
> - [Elliptic divisibility sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_divisibility_sequence)
>   are another class of such sequences.

The $q$-analog $\,[n]_q = U_n(1,q)\,$ is a special case of Lucas
sequences. Given a divisibility sequence, there is associated an
analog of the factorials and binomial coefficients. For example,
[Fibonomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonomial_coefficient)
are based on the Fibonacci sequence which is a special case of a
Lucas sequence.

This analog has applications as in the 2020 paper "Combinatorial
Interpretations of Lucas Analogues of Binomial Coefficients and
Catalan Numbers". There is an earlier 2009 paper "Combinatorial interpretations of binomial coefficient analogues related to Lucas sequences" by Sagan and Savage.

Another different generalization of $\,[n]_q\,$ comes from the
theory of elliptic hypergeometric functions. For example, one
definition of *elliptic numbers* is from a 2020 paper "Elliptic
and $q$-Analogs of the Fibonomial Numbers" by Bergeron, Ceballos
and Kustner. First define the notations

$$ (a;p)_\infty := \prod_{k=0}^\infty(1-ap^k), \quad
(a_1,\dots,a_m;p)_\infty := (a_1;p)_\infty\cdots(a_m;p)_\infty $$

and

$$ \theta(x;p) := (x,p/x;p)_\infty, \quad
\theta((a_1,\dots,a_m;p)_\infty := \theta(a_1;p)_\infty
\cdots\theta(a_m;p)_\infty. $$

Their definition of *elliptic number* is

$$ [n]_{a,b,q,p} := \frac{\theta(q^n,aq^n,bq,\frac{a}{b}q;p)}
{\theta(q,aq,bq^n,\frac{a}{b}q^n;p)}. $$

Further combinatorial applications is from a 2017 paper "Elliptic
rook and file numbers" by Schlosser and Yoo. They have the formulas

$$ \theta(x;p) = - x\theta(1/x;p), \qquad \theta(px;p) = \theta(x;p)/x. $$

and the addition formula

$$ \theta(xy,x/y,uv,u/v;p) - \theta(xv,x/v,uy,u/y;p) =
\theta(yv,y/v,xu,x/u;p)u/y. $$

Their definition of *elliptic number* is slightly different:

$$ [z]_{a,b;q,p} = \frac{\theta(q^z,aq^z,bq^2,a/b;p)}
{\theta(q,aq,bq^{z+1},aq^{q-1}/b,p)}. $$

Comment: This is really interesting! Thanks for introducing me to divisibility sequences

Comment: building on this comment, you might want to look at work by Sagan and co-authors on so-called Lucas analogues, which are bivariate (q,t)-analogues that generalize many positivity phenomena for q-analogues

Comment: @ZachH Thanks for your comment! Perhaps you are mean something like "Combinatorial Interpretations of Lucas Analogues of Binomial Coefficients and Catalan Numbers" from 2020. This seems interesting because of the Combinatorial angle.

Comment: probably the most interesting paper on this topic is about Lucas atoms, joint with Tirell, but the first Lucas analogue for binomial coefficients is a joint paper with Carla Savage fro 2009(10?)

Comment: @ZachH Okay, I have added mention of Sagan and Savage. The "Lucas atoms" are just the obvious natural generalization of cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: @Somos Another analogue I've seen is $[n]_{p,q} = (p^n - q^n)/(p-q)$, which I suspect is a specialization of the elliptic numbers, though it's not immediately obvious to me. See e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669807000194?via%3Dihub#sec5

Comment: @ZachH That is Lucas sequence $U_n$ It generalizes to elliptic numbers. Read my "WXYZ Math Project".